# Print LinkedList Recursively using C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function that would print out my link list recursively, but I'm having trouble doing that, because recursion is just hard.

This is the function I wrote, obviously takes a parameter, but I don't know how to pass it. And probably the output is wrong.

I used typedef:

```
 typedef struct node* nodePtr;
```

and thanks to the input from one of the guys, I updated my function to look like this, but now visual studio is giving an error that says:

"Declaration is incompatible with void List::PrintListRecursively", so I wonder that the way I pass the parameter is just a slight different.

thank you in advance

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(nodePtr curr ){

    if (curr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << curr->data <<endl;
    PrintListRecursively(curr->next);


}
```

I wrote the same function not recursively:

```
void List::PrintList(){
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->data <<endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

and this one works great. Could somebody help out with the recursion part and help me find out whats wrong. Don't be too mean.

Comment: What is the problem with the recursive example? Why is the output wrong? Could you post a small working example?

Comment: Recursion isn't hard. Declare the parameter in the function definition. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your recursive version needs an input:

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(Node* curr)
{
    if (curr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << curr->data <<endl;
    PrintListRecursively(curr->next);
}
```

Which you would then call using the head pointer:

```
list.PrintListRecursively(list.GetHead());
```

Or you could create a version that takes no parameters:

```
void List::PrintListRecursively()
{
    PrintListRecursively(GetHead());
}
```

Which calls the version that takes the pointer parameter.