# Print LinkedList Recursively using C++ Part 2

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to print my list recursively but I'm having trouble with it. The output is infinity 2.......2.....till my computer crashes.

My recursive function is as follows:

```
//void List::PrintListRecursively()
void List::PrintListRecursively(){

    if (curr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << curr->data <<endl;
    PrintListRecursively();
}
```

My main function is as follows:

```
int  main()
{
    List myList;


    myList.insertAtTail(2);
    myList.insertAtTail(3);
    myList.insertAtHead(0);
    myList.insertAtHead(-1);
    myList.insertAtHead(-2);
    myList.PrintListRecursively();

}
```

My original recursive function was the below code, but I don't know how to pass the parameter to the original function since it is a void function. The function doesn't have to be void, I just don't know how to pass a pointer to a function, especially recursively. Recursion always throws me off.

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(){

    if (curr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << curr->data <<endl;
    PrintListRecursively(curr->next);
}
```

somebody suggested:

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(Node* curr)
```

since I'm using typedef: typedef struct node* nodePtr;
I tried this:

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(nodePtr curr)
```

but I just get this error: Declaration is incompatible with void List::PrintListRecursively

Help please

Comment: Do your declaration and definition match for `PrintListRecursively`?

Comment: This question is almost identical to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226797/print-linkedlist-recursively-using-c) - please stick to the existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just get this error: `Declaration is incompatible with void List::PrintListRecursively`

Your declaration and definition must match.  You can keep your public function that takes no parameters, then provide a second implementation.  So your declarations look like this:

```
class List {
   //...
   public:
      void PrintListRecursively();

   private:
      void PrintListRecursively(nodePtr curr);
};
```

And the definitions:

```
void List::PrintListRecursively(){
    PrintListRecursively(head);
}

void List::PrintListRecursively(nodePtr curr) {
    if (curr==NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << curr->data <<endl;
    PrintListRecursively(curr->next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second version has the correct idea, to advance to the next list element before the recursive call, but doesn't implement it correctly. Since `PrintListRecursively` is defined on the `List` itself (in contrast to *receiving* a `List` instance), the correct way to advance is by invoking the method on the next element, without arguments.

In other words, your second implementation needs to end with `cur->next->PrintListRecursively();`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in this implementation the list nodes do not contain list functions.  The list itself appears to do all the work.

Comment: @paddy Good point. Given the invocation of `PrintListRecursively`, I assumed a C-style list where the list *is* the head node. But this is apparently contradicted by the existence of `insertAtHead` and `insertAtTail` methods, which indicate that there is a "tail" and "head" available in `List`. If that is indeed the case, a recursive implementation will require a helper function, as described in your answer.